# How click in input with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem, I'm trying to make a script that automatically logs into this site https://www.nike.com.br/cosmic-unity-153-169-211-324680
The problem is that after a few seconds this page loads and you must select the size of the shoe and click on the button that is written "Faça login para comprar" ok, after my bot clicks there it opens a pop up where i must inform my email and password and click on the login button, the problem is that i'm trying and i can't click on the input to fill in the email and password and neither  I can click on the login button, I believe that maybe it is due to the fact that it is inside a div

**My code:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options                                           
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC                                
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By    
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys                                                 

option = Options()                              
prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values': {'images': 2}}                                
option.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = option)   
driver.get("https//www.nike.com.br/cosmic-unity-153-169-211-324680")                           
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)                 
wait.untilEC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.cc-allow'))).click()       
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//label[@for="tamanho__id40"]'))).click()    
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#anchor-acessar-unite-oauth2'))).click()                                         
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input#9f656f67-dbed-4cda-be83-0d0d0addc6f4'))).send_keys("test@gmail.com")                                             
wait.untillEC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input#7016e824-f431-43d0-b5c9-d0331c330014'))).send_keys("mypass")                   
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#a7f38f9a-afd7-42ce-a978-314a7d484343'))).click()
```

Order this code and realize that it only works until you open the login popup, after that it generates this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That pop up is inside an iframe, you need to switch your driver focus to that particular iframe.

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"nike-unite-oauth2-iframe")))
```

make sure once you are done with that pop up switch to default_content to proceed further.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

**Update 1 :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\etc\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.nike.com.br/cosmic-unity-153-169-211-324680")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.cc-allow'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='tamanho__id40']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#anchor-acessar-unite-oauth2'))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"nike-unite-oauth2-iframe")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'emailAddress'))).send_keys("test@gmail.com")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'password'))).send_keys("mypass")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[value='ENTRAR']"))).click()
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand, how would this be added to my code?

Comment: Before you jump on that pop up write the first line `frame_to_it` and then you can have email and password and click on login

Comment: Add this snippet of code `wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"nike-unite-oauth2-iframe")))`  after this line in my code ` wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#anchor-acessar-unite-oauth2'))).click()` and in the last line of my code I added this `driver.switch_to.default_content()` and the error is the same

Comment: Could you assemble your solution and apply it to my code and add it to the body of the answer?  because I'm not sure I got it right

Comment: Same error `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:` :(

Comment: @Gjsks : It works perfectly fine on my machine, there are few "" and '' issue also I fixed in your code. Are you sure that you are running all the lines in sequence and from update1 section ?

Comment: @Gjsks : Are you maximizing your browser screen ? I have updated few details under section 1.. try it out and let me know if there is any more concerns

Comment: Friend, I saw it here and I had really done something wrong, I did exactly the same as your example now and it worked almost everything, just the part of the enter button that didn’t work, don’t click the button

Comment: @Gjsks : My bad. I thought it was a name attribute anyway use this line to click on enter button `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[value='ENTRAR']"))).click()`

Comment: Man, thank you very much, I have 5 hours to finish this script and I haven't slept yet, I could do it in node js and pupeteer but I chose to do it in Selenium and I'm finding it difficult lol but I will only sleep when I'm done hehe